# Test react services using jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

Is there a way to test a service using jest?
I was trying to do that but the test doesn't seem to run.

```
import { postAuthUser } from '../authService';

it('login user', () => {
  return postAuthUser({ username: 'user', password: 'password' }).then( data => {
    expect(data).toEqual({});
  });
});
```

I have this, I am trying to consume a service but for some reason, it doesn't work.

Comment: why is `toEqual` a null object?

Comment: That should be the user data, I have it into a const, but the issue is that the API call is not done, and also when I use a a mock adapter(axios-mock-adapter) I got undefined in the response.

Answer (score 3):

I assume your `postAuthUser` method of `authService` use `axios` like this:

`authService.ts`

```
import axios from 'axios';

export async function postAuthUser(auth) {
  return axios.post('https://github.com/mrdulin', auth);
}
```

Unit test:

```
import { postAuthUser } from './authService';
import axios from 'axios';

jest.mock('axios', () => {
  return {
    post: jest.fn()
  };
});

describe('authService', () => {
  describe('#postAuthUser', () => {
    it('login user', () => {
      (axios.post as jest.MockedFunction<typeof axios.post>).mockResolvedValueOnce({});
      return postAuthUser({ username: 'user', password: 'password' }).then(data => {
        expect(data).toEqual({});
        expect(axios.post).toBeCalledWith('https://github.com/mrdulin', { username: 'user', password: 'password' });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/53934331/authService.spec.ts
  authService
    #postAuthUser
      ✓ login user (5ms)

----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File            |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files       |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 authService.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.483s, estimated 4s
```

Here is the completed demo:
https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/53934331